# How to get a count of a items within a collection that match a specific criteria?

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a collection like so:

```
{ "items": [
    {
     "id": "123",
     "meta": {
        "activity": 2
     }
    },
    {
     "id": "13423",
     "meta": {
        "activity": 4
     }
    }
]}
```

Given the collection, how can I get the collection's total activity? In the case above the result would be 6.

I'm using backbone and underscore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using underscore.js, so you have some good tools at your disposal. Look at [_.map()](http://underscorejs.org/#map) to get started.

```
var flatArray = _.map(collection.items, function(x){return x.meta.activity;});
// should return: [2,4]
```

Then you can use [_.reduce()](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce) to turn this into a single value.

```
var total = _.reduce(flatArray, function(memo, num) {return memo + num;}, 0);
// should return: 6
```

There's lots of other great tools in underscore.js, it's worth a look to see if anything else would work for you too.

Answer (score 1):

In underscore you can use the [reduce](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce) function which will reduce a list of values into a single value using the given iterator function.

```
var myCollection = { "items": [
    {
        "id": "123",
        "meta": {
            "activity": 2
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "13423",
        "meta": {
            "activity": 4
        }
    }
]};

var totalActivity = _.reduce(myCollection.items, function(memo, item){ return memo + item.meta.activity; }, 0);
```